# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 76,Token in error = = ]

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm working with VS 2010 .Net 4.0 and SQL Server CE 3.5.
I've made a database with a table and connected to it.

```
// string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.EPwlConnectionString;
// DB=EPwl tabel=PHfilters
// coloms= Subkey  | CLSID
```

The table is populated with strings. A colomn can have the same Subkey or CLSID, but never the same Subkey|CLSID combination. The row subkey|CLSID is unique.

I want to check if this combination is present with a query or return *string.Empthy* if it isn't.
So far I got this code:

```
string subkey = "test"; // for testing purposes
string clsid = "0123456789"; // for testing purposes
string sb = string.Empty;
bool known = false;
string cmd = "SELECT [Subkey], [CLSID] 
FROM PHfilters 
WHERE [Subkey] = @subkey & [CLSID] = @clsid";
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
 con.Open();
 using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(cmd, con))
 {
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("subkey", subkey);
  com.Parameters.AddWithValue("clsid", clsid);
  SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read())
   {
     sb = reader["CLSID"].ToString();                                       
    }
    if (sb == string.Emphty)
    {
     // Unknown
     known = false;

    }
    else
    {
      known = true;

    }
   }
  }
```

But it doesn't work and give me the error at the SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader() line.

Can anyone point me the bug in this code please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `AND` instead of `&`? I can't say I've ever seen `&` used like that in SQL.

Comment: Yeah! *slap on forehead* That get me loose the error.
I was following the techNet info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173290.aspx, but I seem to misinterpret the info.

&(AND) bitwise

Thank you so much, sir !!